# Конфликт библиотек Realm и Crosswalk

Tags: android, webview, realm, realm-database

Доброго времени суток.
В моем проекте я использую библиотеки Realm и Crosswalk. Realm я заимпортил через gradle следующим путем:

Project gradle

```
dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.2.1"
    }
```

App module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

а библиотеку Crosswalk заимпортил в качестве проекта ( а не через gradle ). И когда я запускаю мое приложение, оно сразу же закрывается со следующими логами:

```
I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
D/XWalkLib: Pre init xwalk core in com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkActivity: Initialize by XWalkInitializer
D/XWalkLib: DecompressTask started
W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
D/XWalkLib: Reserve object class com.app.myapp.CustomView.MyXwalkView to com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkLib: Reserve object class com.app.myapp.LoginActivty$ResourceClient to com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkLib: Reserve method setResourceClient to com.app.myapp.LoginActivty
D/XWalkLib: DecompressTask finished, 0
D/XWalkLib: ActivateTask started
D/XWalkLib: Attach xwalk core
D/XWalkLib: [App Version] build:22.52.561.4, api:7, min_api:1
D/XWalkLib: [Lib Version] build:22.52.561.4, api:7, min_api:5
D/XWalkLib: Crosswalk download mode: false
D/XWalkLib: XWalk core version matched
D/XWalkLib: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.myapp-2/lib/arm64, /system/fake-libs64, /data/app/com.app.myapp-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libxwalkcore.so"
D/XWalkLib: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/user/0/com.app.myapp/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so" not found
D/XWalkLib: Device ABI: arm64-v8a
D/XWalkLib: org.xwalk.core not found
D/XWalkLib: org.xwalk.core64 not found
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
D/XWalkLib: ActivateTask finished, 6
D/XWalkLib: Crosswalk APK download URL: 
D/XWalkLib: HttpDownloadTask started, 
E/XWalkLib: Invalid download URL 
D/XWalkLib: HttpDownloadTask finished, -1
```

Но когда удаляю нотации о Realm из Gradle, Crosswalk прекрасно работает ... Вопрос: как я могу использовать одновременно и Realm, и Crosswalk ?

Comment: а счего вы взяли что это конфликт библиотек Realm и Crosswalk, а не ошибка в использовании Realm?

Comment: На других устройствах нормально работает.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно, проблема тут конфликтов нативных библиотек. Я далеко не эксперт в этой области, но в ваших логах написано, что неможет найти нативные файлы ("libxwalkcore.so")

```
D/XWalkLib: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app.myapp-2/lib/arm64, /system/fake-libs64, /data/app/com.app.myapp-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libxwalkcore.so"
D/XWalkLib: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/user/0/com.app.myapp/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so" not found
```

Есть приложение в play market, что мониторить нативные либы в апк файле [Native libs monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app). Оно довольно простое и интуитивно понятное, может помочь, в понимании, чего не хватает, и например будет ли этот файл в апк, если выпилить Рилм.

Скорее всего проблема в том, что присутствет конфликт использования разных архитектур процессоров. Вам предстоит например форсировать использование Рилмом 64битной архитектуры,потому что у вас вторая либо именно ее и использует, если я правильно понял из лога.
Скорее всего, это можно сделать через Gradle, нечто подобное у нас в команде было, когда мы экспирементировали в одном проекте с Рилмом. Было это давно, много воды утекло, к тому же не я тогда это фиксил.
Но возможно поможет добавления abiFilters в Gradle defaultConfig ->

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
   minSdkVersion 15
   targetSdkVersion 23
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
   defaultConfig
   ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
   }

}
buildTypes {
    . . . 
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['lib']
    }
}
```

Также попробуйте почитать [тут](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/issues/305), случай похож на  ваш и похоже тут есть то, что нужно (пусть и речь не конкретно р Рилме). Если не помогло, не отчаивайтесь и поэкспериментируйте с фильтрами, погуглите, изучите предметную область. Уверен все получиться, удачи !